# What does "otherwise than" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does "otherwise than" mean in this sentence?

> [...]a very extensive territory cannot be governed on the principles of freedom, **otherwise than** by a confederacy of republics[...]

Is is saying that an extensive territory *can* be governed on principles of freedom by a confederacy of republics? Or is it saying that an extensive territory *cannot* be governed on principles of freedom by a confederacy of republics?

If it helps here is a snapshot of the document:
[image: picture of document, the phrase in question is highlighted]

Comment: ***Otherwise than***: *in any way except the way that you are mentioning* - *A partnership cannot be ended otherwise than by mutual agreement*. http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/otherwise-than - so....*a very estensive territory ***can be governed only*** by a confederation of republics.*

Comment: so it means to say 'extensive territory can be governed on principles of freedom by a confederacy of republics', Thanks!

Comment: What @JOSH said - *in another way than*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*other than* or *except by*

> [...]a very extensive territory cannot be governed on the principles of freedom, other than by a confederacy of republics[...]

or

> [...]a very extensive territory cannot be governed on the principles of freedom, except by a confederacy of republics[...]